# What does "apache2ctl:: command not found" mean if Apache IS installed and running?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, configuration

Trying to run the command "apache2ctl restart" and just got this message "apache2ctl:: command not found" -- thing is, Apache IS installed, running, and I'm actively doing development on the server right now... any ideas?

**CONTEXT:** sudo access on CentOS-5.5 on VM

---

**UPDATE:** Good news, restarted Apache, bad news 500 error, still it's progress... :-)

```
[username@VMname /]$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
[username@VMname /]$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `apache2ctl` isn't in your path. Try this instead:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl restart
```

The above location reflects the location of `apache2ctl` in Ubuntu. I'm not sure where the default location is on CentOS. If the above command doesn't work, you can find the location by running the following as root:

```
$ which apache2ctl
```

Comment: **@ErikA:** Thanks! So, I did a find as sudo of the whole computer for a apache2ctl, and nothing. There is a apachectl, but that's not for Apache2 I don't believe (info.php is reporting the system as Apache2); "which apache2ctl", didn't work either, but appears to have confirmed it check in the bin directories; sbin was not listed, but that's where I found apachectl.   Really have no idea. Are there any httpd conf that would point to it, guessing not but have no idea at this point. "sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart echo $?" did appear to execute and return what appears to be a httpd help page.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is restart apache, why don't you just use the init script? `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`?

Comment: **@ErikA:** See above... :-)

Comment: I think in 'Enterprise Linux' and Fedora, `apachectl` is equivalent to `apahe2ctl` in Debian distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Did any response was helpful?

I think you should be using httpd commands due to you are using Centos (RedHat)

I started looking for httpd commands too, they are not the same as the majority of examples we can find on the internet (referring to apache2 - Debian based distributions)